# Assign title-specific class to list items in menu based on WP pages

Tags: css, pages, navigation

I'm currently using a WP-generated list of pages for my site navigation - this is using the method `wp_page_menu`.

I'd like to add custom styling to specfic list items in the menu, and I was wondering if it's possible to have a function that will assign class names to the list items based on the name of the page they link to.

So, for example, instead of having to apply styles to `li.page-item-1500`, I'd like to apply styles to the list item generated from the page's title, such as `li.about`.  Is this possible?

(I'm using WP ver 3.3.1, btw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - you can do this without having to write any code, too.

- On the 'Menus' page, locate the 'Screen Options' at the top of the page and locate the 'CSS Classes' check box. Click it.

[image]

- After that, expand a menu item and you'll see a new option for 'CSS Classes'

[image]

Comment: Perfect - thanks for that Tom. I just had to change the function from `wp_page_menu` to `wp_nav_menu` and I was away.